# jplayer multiple mp3 file links in one page

Tags: jplayer

I use jplayer in my page and when clicked a link I want to play the clicked one. However every time test1.mp3 is played. How can I solve it? The code is below:

the page is as follows if needed:

http://www.dilyurdu.com/audio.htm

```
function listen(mp3_index){ 

    var mp3_file;
    mp3_file="test"+mp3_index+".mp3";


     $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({ 
        ready: function(event) { 
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", { 
                mp3: mp3_file, 
        }); 
     }, 
    swfPath: "http://www.jplayer.org/2.1.0/js", 
    supplied: "mp3" 
  });   

}
```

links are as follows:

```
<div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>

<a href="javascript:listen(1);" class="jp-play" >play 1</a><br /><br />     

<a href="javascript:listen(2);" class="jp-play" >play 2</a><br /><br />

<a href="javascript:listen(3);" class="jp-play" >play 3</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Hey you can do the following.

I instantiate the player on page load:

```
jQuery("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
  swfPath: "http://www.jplayer.org/latest/js/Jplayer.swf",
  supplied: "mp3",
  wmode: "window",
  preload:"auto",
  autoPlay: true,
  errorAlerts:false,
  warningAlerts:false
});
```

Then inside a listener, which will be unique for every item,
you need to:
A) **Fetch track name/URL**, I guess you should be able to figure this out.

B) **Pass the track to the setMedia**

```
  jQuery("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("setMedia", {
    mp3: "http:xxxx.rackcdn.com/"+track+".MP3"
  });
```

C) **Play the track**

```
  jQuery("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("play");
```

To get the track Id you need to install listeners on your playable items(maybe a a playable class?) and get the track from that one.

Answer (score 0):

i am also looking for a solution for this.
Just created it in jsfiddle visit http://jsfiddle.net/vijayweb/A5LQF/2/

It plays only one song. any help will be grateful.

---

I found a relevant solution...still play only the first default song.
[multiple mp3 links in a single page with jplayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471327/multiple-mp3-links-in-a-single-page-with-jplayer)

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<a class="ChangePath" data-key="1" href="javascript:void(0);">Song1</a>
<a class="ChangePath" data-key="2" href="javascript:void(0);">Song1</a>
<a class="ChangePath" data-key="3" href="javascript:void(0);">Song1</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $('.ChangePath').on('click', function () {

    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("destroy");

    var link = "test" + $(this).data('key') + ".mp3";

    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function () {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                mp3: link
            });
        },
        swfPath: "~/Scripts/jplayer",
        supplied: "mp3"
    });

    player.jPlayer("play", 0);

});
});
```

If you are using ajax:

```
$(function () {
    $('.ChangePath').on('click', function () {
   $.ajax({
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("destroy");

    var link = "test" + $(this).data('key') + ".mp3";

    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function () {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                mp3: link
            });
        },
        swfPath: "~/Scripts/jplayer",
        supplied: "mp3"
    });

    player.jPlayer("play", 0);
});
});
});
```

Depending on your project you might need to change the hyperlinks to something else, but the jQuery will work.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.reproducirContenedor').on('click',function(e){// click en el elento a reproducir
    e.preventDefault();//para que cuando el usuario haga click en el icono de play no salte la pagina


    jQuery("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        swfPath: "http://www.jplayer.org/latest/js/Jplayer.swf",
        supplied: "mp3",
        wmode: "window",
        preload:"auto",
        autoPlay: true,
        errorAlerts:false,
        warningAlerts:false
      });
   
    var url_destino=$(this).attr('data-demo');// obtengo la ubicacion del archivo de audio para reproducirlo



    jQuery("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("setMedia", {
        mp3:url_destino
      });

      jQuery("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("play");
    
        
});
```